код для решения задачи C++ codewars
Задача:
"in this little assignment you are given a string of space separated numbers, and have to return the highest and lowest number.
Examples
   highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5");  // return "5 1"
   highAndLow("1 2 -3 4 5"); // return "5 -3"
   highAndLow("1 9 3 4 -5"); // return "9 -5"

Notes
All numbers are valid Int32, no need to validate them.
There will always be at least one number in the input string.
Output string must be two numbers separated by a single space, and highest number is first."
мой код:
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string highAndLow(const string& numbers){
  string::iterator it;
  int h, l;
  for(it = &numbers.begin(); it != &numbers.end(); ++it) {
    if (it == &numbers.begin()) {
      h = (int*)it;
      l = (int*)it;
    }
    else {
      if (h < (int)it) {
        h = (int*)it;
      }
      if (l > (int*)it) {
        l = (int*)it;
      }
    }
    return string(h + " " + l + "\n");
  }
}

Я начал учить срр только несколько дней назад, пожалуйста, не судите строго.

В этом вопросе нет собственно вопроса.

я просто спросил, есть ли ошибки

Нет, вы не спрашивали. А разве код даёт верные ответы для всех примеров?

А вы его хоть компилировать пытались?... по-моему, нет.

Посмотрите на atoi

у меня компилятора нет.

"у меня компилятора нет" - вот это поворот... Обычно обучение С/С++ начинается с обзаведения компилятором и сборки "hello world". Вот с этого и стоит начинать. А на codewards и подобные злачные ресурсы время тратить не стоит.

я не понимаю, почему он не работае. Я скачал visual studio 2022, но когда туда захожу вылазит окошко "войдите в аккаунт" и кнопка, чтобы закрыть программу. Даже когда я вошёл в аккаунт, оно не согласилось закрыться.

Начнем с того, что ваш код просто не компилируется.
А если бы и компилировался — то не работал бы. Итератор строки перебирает символы, и он никакого отношения к int не имеет, да и присвоение переменной типа int чего-то, приведенного к int*...
Словом, все плохо :(
Я бы делал так:
string highAndLow(const string& numbers)
{
    istringstream is(numbers);
    int n, min, max;
    is >> n;
    min = max = n;
    while(is >> n)
        if (n < min) min = n;
        else if (n > max) max = n;
    return to_string(max) + " " + to_string(min);
}

Или даже вот так:
string highAndLow(const string& numbers)
{
    istringstream is(numbers);
    auto p = minmax_element(istream_iterator<int>(is),istream_iterator<int>());
    return to_string(*p.second) + " " + to_string(*p.first);
}


я сейчас понял, что есть онлайн компиляторы. Из вашего кода половину не понял.
#include 
using namespace std;
string highAndLow(const string& numbers){
int curr_num;
int h, l;
for(int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(numbers); i++) {
curr_num = int(numbers[i]);
if (i == 0) {
h = curr_num;
l = curr_num;
}
else {
if (h < curr_num) {
h = curr_num;
}
if (l > curr_num) {
l = curr_num;
}
}
}
return string(to_string(h) + " " + to_string(l));
}
int main() {
cout << highAndLow("1 2 3 4");
}

что значит is >> n???

Бросим в воду и посмотрим, сможет ли после этого он сам плавать классическим баттерфляем?

@avp Если поступить иначе, будут говорить, что я решаю домашние задания за лентяев :) А вот если есть решение и человек будет разбираться, как оно работает, самостоятельно.. 2 deado: это чтение переменной n из потока is.

*p. -> p->.
